# Unable to deploy app to App engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a GWT based web application that I have previously uploaded to Appspot.
However now, I am getting this error:

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:583)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:434)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:327)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:52)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:400)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

- The application used JDK (not JRE)
- There's a JSP file (dummy) on the    war file
- The application works in hosted mode

Comment: try cleaning the project and recompiling it.

Comment: I have recompiled it, still getting the same problem

Comment: encountered same problem after upgrading to appengine SDK 1.7.5

Comment: I had the same problem; I use manual compilation with batch files. I tried the ant build file
and ran ant clean. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a clean build first.  Alt+P, N in eclipse.  If this fails, delete /war/WEB-INF/classes and try again.  If this also fails, right click your war folder and select validate; this will tell you if there are any actual errors in your jsp files.

If this fails, your appengine jars may be corrupted.  Try unzipping a fresh SDK and using it to deploy.

Also, have you changed java versions recently? Compiling JSPs requires JAVA_HOME points to a JDK, not a JRE.  What is the result of `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: I did, still getting the same problem

Comment: If you've had any IDE crashes, they can sometimes randomly corrupt your appengine jars.  Try unzipping a fresh sdk, and using it to deploy instead.  If you aren't already, try the command line deploy, `/path/to/sdk/bin/appcfg.sh update /path/to/project/war`

I also get this problem if eclipse is compiling my files while I try to deploy.  Make sure your IDE isn't doing anything in /war when you try.

Answer (score 0):

this thread will solve your problem
[Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985363/cannot-get-the-system-java-compiler-please-use-a-jdk-not-a-jre/26945894#26945894)

Other wise, you need to set your  JAVA_HOME to point to your jdk folder and add javaw.exe path in your eclipse.ini

Comment: An if that thread won't solve your problem, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638655/google-app-engine-failed-to-compile-the-generated-jsp-java-files