# Google AppEngine not displaying web pages

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp

I have installed Google API in my Eclipse 4.3(Kepler). I am trying to deploy my existing project to it but it doesn't so I have copy /paste my directory like `web-content`, java resources `src` directory and it's sub directory.

I gives me some error of `import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;` package also.
all other code works fine.
I deploy project on AppEngine but when I am trying to access it's webpages then it doesn't show.

My appengine url is something like http://keyurdatadrive.appspot.com

when I am trying to access my page slog.jsp like http://keyurdatadrive.appspot.com/slogin.jsp then it gives me an error.

```
The requested URL /slogin.jsp was not found on this server.
```

anyone tell me that what to do to deploy my existing project to it ?

And why I can't access my pages ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You seem to mention that there is a problem deploying but then you mention that the application did get deployed. Does the file slogin.jsp exist? Are you able to access it on your local dev server?

Comment: @ on my local server I can access it and deployment also done but I can't access it. I actually don;t know hierarchy of project or structure of project of AppEngine. Can I deploy my existing project ?

Comment: If you have used the standard New Web Application Project Wizard for the Project, then the default WAR like structure is created for you. All your JSP files can go for the moment into /war folder. You will see that folder in your project structure. Do one thing. Just create a new project for now and deselect Google Web Toolkit. Validate that stuff works by default. Then add your slogin.jsp page inside the /war folder and then check again.

Comment: Ok let me try again sir then I ll inform you. Sir can I deploy my existing project or not ? Because I have completed my project and it's so complicate so is there any mechanism that is useful to deploy it ?

Comment: I suggest you try things locally first and then deploy.

Comment: Sir when I am adding jsp files in war directory it gives an error symbol on that jsp files, when I open it, there is no error inside it.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to debug your problem since one would need to look at your Eclipse settings, the GAE SDK and JDK settings. Does the default app generated by the wizard along with one JSP thrown in the WAR directory, work or not?

Comment: Yes that works, welcome.html file that is inside war file runs on web.

Comment: So, does the project work now ? Go ahead and place a JSP file in the same folder as your welcome.html file. It should work.

Comment: But now when I done that and trying to deploy that one then it gives me an error that use JDK instead of JRE in Java Compiler.

Comment: Thats good. You are getting there now. Open up your Eclipse settings and go to Java. In that make sure you are using JDK and not the JRE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985363/cannot-get-the-system-java-compiler-please-use-a-jdk-not-a-jre

Comment: Now It works sir. But the error symbol still on each jsp page. And how to do Database connection in that, where to make DB and how to do it's configuration in our code ? Bas ab thodi hi help ki jarur hai.

Comment: Oh no, it's billing on Google App Engine. Now what to do ? Is there any place where I can test my App Free with DB ? Any help sir ji.

Comment: Well, when it comes to storage - you have multiple options. There is the Datastore that has a free quota. The Cloud SQL is billable though. I suggest you read up on Datastore, it will take some time to get used to if you are coming from a SQL world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add slogin.jsp to  in web.xml?

read this: [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml?hl=pl#The_Welcome_File_List)

Comment: no i don't have added `slogin.jsp` i `web.xml`, It have entry of only `welcome.html`

Comment: I do not think that an entry is needed in the welcome file list, as long as you are explicitly invoking the JSP file in the url.

Comment: @Romin yes it's not necessary. So maybe try remove 'welcome.html' and add 'slogin.jsp' and use [http://keyurdatadrive.appspot.com](http://keyurdatadrive.appspot.com)