# Android studio error After run the project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I am getting following error while trying to run my app from android studio

`Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'. Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory`.

After searching on internet, I found some solution like this

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/
```

so i gave this command in terminal from android studio dirctory but its not workout it show the same error again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985363/cannot-get-the-system-java-compiler-please-use-a-jdk-not-a-jre  see this

Comment: If you are on Wiondows try to run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%` in command prompt and include the outputs in question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In your android-studio 
 find it in File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure->SDKs. Then i changed JDK home path.

Answer (score 69):

Updating my Gradle build version did the trick for me.

Old:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

New:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Edit: Since this answer is still being used frequently, note that Gradle 2.2.3 can probably be substituted with any newer version of Gradle. This version just happened to be the version I was using when I originally answered the question.

Comment: This is definitely the answer for most, thanks @eatcrayons, this always messes me up when compiling Google Sample Code.

Comment: @eatcrayons Thank You. you saved my time +1 vote for u

Answer (score 5):

To fix this error in Andriod Studio 2.3.1 I had to go to `File > Project Structure` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then go to SDK Location which was already open for me and then uncheck "Use embedded JDK" and point to where my installed version was.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this error in Andriod Studio 2.3.1 I had to go to File > Project Structure or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then go to SDK Location which was already open for me and then uncheck "Use embedded JDK" and point to where my installed version was.

*

> The mentioned post really solved my problem after long searching.

*

Answer (score 1):

In the android studio

Window -> preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and select your JDK home path

or else please follow the [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/) to set JAVA_HOME in linux machines

Answer (score 1):

In your android-studio find it in File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure->SDKs.
Then Check with JDK LOCATION select Installed JDK Location and APPLY IT.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem a lot when I try to open older projects for the first time.  It seems that I just need to update the classpath under build.gradle:

In my case the old version was:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'`
and I updated to:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'`

Sync the gradle and it should compile.