# Runtime exception when deploying to Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, ubuntu

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985363/cannot-get-the-system-java-compiler-please-use-a-jdk-not-a-jre) and none of the existing answers were particularly helpful.

The error message is

> "Unable to stage app: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use
>   a JDK, not a JRE."

---

`$JAVA_HOME`

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

`$PATH`

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin:/home/ukraine/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin:/home/ukraine/Downloads/Libraries/Python/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/home/ukraine/bin:/home/ukraine/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

`eclipse.ini`

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
/root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I needed to use the Oracle JDK instead of the Open JDK